# Planck's Hypothesis Derivation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, quantization

Max Planck in 1900 used the quantisation of energy to explain black body radiation.
Using what principles did he arrive at his final formula $E=nhv$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He *guessed* the answer, and saw that it worked. (i..e agreed with experiment) Physics is not math. Not everything is derived from something else.

To be more precise though: Planck decided to redo the  derivation of the integrals in standard  black body spectrum with more mathematical care. He started by allowing only energies $E= n h \nu$ in his calculation with the intention of taking the limit $h\to 0$ at the end. He found that if he did take the limit he ended up with the usual ulta-violet catastrophe, but, if he kept $h$ finite, the  resulting energy-frequency plot fitted the data.

Comment: You mean the integral of Rayleigh Jeans law. right?

Comment: Yes. However, I think it worth looking at the Wikipedia article on Planck and his discovery. It seems that he had another non-discrete energy "derivation" before the one that I remember reading about ---  but there is no link in the Wiki article, so some historical invertigation might be fun to do.

Comment: Yeah...Thank you

Comment: Holy smokes! Thats F-ing awesome. So, he indeed got a nobel prize and changed the world due to some accidental mathematics.